# Animation start from Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have make a Map with 30 Overlays that will zoom in at start.
But the Animation (zoom in) is showing before the tiles from the Map are showing. After the Animation, Map is loading the tiles. It is happening everytime. Also after a destroy and reload.
Is there any way to say that the Animation starts after the tiles are loaded ?

```
@Override
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

                        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(new LatLng(52.33101, 7.91667 ))      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                                .zoom(9)                   
                                .bearing(0)                
                                .tilt(60)                   
                                .build();                   
                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), 10000, null);

                        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(52.2056, 7.70862))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
```

The method can look something like:

```
@Override
public void onMapLoaded() {
if (mMap != null) {
   // animate the camera to desired position
}
```

}

For more info, following is the link:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback

Comment: Thank you. Thats is what i search for.

Comment: Glad it helped you..!